# How to filter (rate-limit) traffic through a bridge, using nftables, depending on whether or not the traffic originated locally?

Tags: ethernet, bridge, mac-address, nftables, loopback

I'd appreciate some help with understanding how traffic filtering in a bridge works, especially for packets / Ethernet frames which originated locally. To explain the problem, I'll shortly describe the situation, the goal, the steps I've taken so far and where I have failed.

**Situation**

On a Linux host (debian buster x64), I have a VM (Qemu / KVM) with Windows Server 2019. For certain reasons, I need to rate-limit all network traffic which goes **into** that VM **from all sources outside the host** (that is, from other physical machines). In contrast, all network traffic **which originates from the host itself** and goes to that VM should **not** be rate-limited.

Windows itself provides QoS mechanisms, but they all either are for outbound traffic only, or are not suitable to solve that problem. Therefore, I decided to try to implement the rate-limiting at the host side.

The VM is connected to the host network by a bridge:

```
root@cerberus /var/log # brctl show br0
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.002590fb7105       no              enp1s0f1
                                                        garak0
```

`garak0`, the second bridge port, is the virtual network adapter of the VM; `enp1s0f1`, the first bridge port, is a physical network adapter. `enp1s0f1` is the only physical network adapter on that host which is connected to the outside; that is, any traffic for that host which originates from other machines comes in through `enp1s0f1`.

The MAC addresses are as follows (leaving out irrelevant lines and a bunch of interfaces which are not of interest here):

```
root@cerberus /var/log # ifconfig -a
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.20.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.20.255
        ether 00:25:90:fb:71:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        ...
enp1s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:25:90:fb:71:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        ...
garak0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b6:89:d8:4e:fa:2c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        ...
```

The MAC address of the other side of the VM's virtual NIC (i.e. the MAC address the O/S in the VM actually sees and which is in the arp cache of machines which are connected to the VM) is `02:01:01:01:16:01`.

**Goal**

Using nftables, I want to rate-limit the traffic which goes to the VM by filtering the bridge traffic at layer 2, keeping in mind that the limit must only apply to traffic from outside the host and that no limit must apply for traffic from the host itself to the VM.

I am almost there, but I am fighting with a detail which stops the show (see below).

**What I have done and what works**

Yesterday I have learned some concepts for nftables (this is my first contact with it) and have created the following ruleset:

```
root@cerberus /var/log # nft list ruleset
table bridge filter1 {
        chain test {
                type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
                ether daddr 02:01:01:01:16:01 limit rate over 10 mbytes/second drop
        }
}
```

It was a steep learning curve, mainly because all examples I saw either showed only how to create the rule, but not the table and the chain, or used the input hook, where `ether daddr` obviously does not work.

Whatsoever, this works in the sense that it indeed limits the traffic rate which reaches the VM to 10 MB/s in average.

**What does not work / My actual problem**

With the ruleset shown above, **all** traffic to the VM is rate-limited, including the traffic originating from the host itself. I tried to correct this by altering the ruleset like that:

```
root@cerberus /var/log # nft list ruleset
table bridge filter1 {
        chain test {
                type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
                ether daddr 02:01:01:01:16:01 ether saddr 00:25:90:fb:71:05 limit rate over 10 mbytes/second drop
        }
}
```

Although I already had suspected, I was disappointed when I saw that now no traffic to the VM at all was rate-limited any more. My hope had been that the Ethernet frames from other physical machines would carry the MAC address from bridge port 1 (i.e. the physical network adapter) as Ethernet source address, because that's the port they enter the bridge through. But (not very surprisingly) that is not the case; probably they carry the sending PC's physical network adapter's MAC address as source address.

So my question is:

How can I alter the rule(set) so that it matches traffic destined to the MAC address of the VM, but does not match the part which originates locally? Probably traffic generated by the host originates from the loopback adapter which does not have a MAC address, so I can't use something like `ether saddr !<MAC of loopback>`.

I have thought of trying `ingress` instead of `bridge` to solve that problem, or to use filtering by device. But the number of possible combinations and pitfalls is endless, so having a starting point would make life easier.

Comment: Thank you very much. Regarding the jitter, this is a misunderstanding - it should be just a remark, not a complaint. Actually, I don't care about it. Regarding the terms, I used "filter" because everybody else seems to do it, too. Probably this is because of the `type filter` in nftables (there is no `type limit` or `type rate`). I will now remove the remark regarding the jitter, and will correct the heading. I'll also look into `tc`, but it seems overly complicated, and I doubt I can learn even the basics in reasonable time, so I'd still be interested in how to do it with nftables.

Comment: @A.B Thank you very much for the effort! Regarding your question: I copied a big file onto the host. Then (on the host) I did `rsync --progress /path/to/big/file Administrator@192.168.20.16:/cygdrive/C/Daten` and watched the transfer rate rsync reported. It was 10 MB/s with the first setup (with some jitter), and was about 50 MB/s with the second setup. For the first setup, I expected that limitation, because the `daddr` is the MAC **the VM O/S sees**, not the MAC of any physical interface or a bridge port on the host. Therefore, nftables must limit all traffic to that MAC address.

Comment: @A.B I am a bit lost about the details which I could give in addition. There is really nothing special - no other bridges, no special network hardware, no custom-compiled software, just a plain Debian buster system on a Supermicro X10DRU-i+ with two E5-2690v3, 128GB and 4x10GbE (Intel X540). I have shown only one of the four physical interfaces in the `ifconfig` output because the other three don't even have a cable attached at the moment, so the interface shown definitely is the only one where network traffic from other machines can come in.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. In the meantime, I have solved the problem that way: `ether daddr 02:01:01:01:16:01 iifname != lo limit rate over 10 mbytes/second drop`. That does what I want. However, I didn't investigate yet whether or not it limits the traffic from other VMs which are on the same bridge.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your last comment. The rule shown in my previous comment did the trick for me, so I don't need anything else at the moment. It limits the rate of traffic from other physical hosts to the VM as desired, and does not limit the rate of traffic from the host itself to the VM. Therefore my problem is solved.